# MySQL Crosstab table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm trying to create a mySQL table for cyclists as they pass through a (variable) number of checkpoints.  I'd like to display the results as a table with the cyclist information in the left column (row header) and the checkpoints in the top row (column header)

The basic schema:

```
CREATE TABLE timing (`Bib` int, `checkpoint` tinytext, `time` datetime);

INSERT INTO timing
    (`Bib` , `checkpoint` , `time`)
VALUES
    (100, 'CP1', '2016-09-22 01:00:00'),
    (101, 'CP1', '2016-09-22 01:30:00'),
    (102, 'CP1', '2016-09-22 02:00:00'),
    (100, 'CP2', '2016-09-22 02:00:00'),
    (101, 'CP2', '2016-09-22 02:30:00'),
    (100, 'CP3', '2016-09-22 03:00:00'),
    (103, 'CP2', '2016-09-22 04:00:00')
;
```

SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
      CONCAT(
      '(CASE WHEN checkpoint = ''',
      checkpoint,
      ''' THEN time else 0 END) AS `',
      checkpoint, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM timing;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT Bib, ', @sql, ' 
            from timing
            group by Bib');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The result is not populating the entire table i.e. I'm only seeing the first time the rider passes the first checkpoint.  If I use an aggregating function in the CONCAT I get numerical values which have to be converted back into datetime? Surely I can just show the datetime without having to multiple steps?

What am I missing?

TIA.

Comment: Please add your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the responses and messages -- the problem was being caused by a relations error and my logic... I now have a lot more complicated solution than I was hoping for, but it works and is actually quite robust.

Yes, 1000111 I did need to use an aggregating function in the end, and convert the result back into a readable format; just one of the many other steps I ended up with :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just missed the `MAX`

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
      CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN checkpoint = ''',
      checkpoint,
      ''' THEN time else 0 END) AS `',
      checkpoint, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM timing;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT Bib, ', @sql, ' 
            from timing
            group by Bib');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50a694/1/4)</kbd>